# Flutter, change character code set with charset_converter package

Tags: flutter, charset

I would like to convert a from json which is in Big5 to UTF-8.  I try with the example from charset_converter package but it gives compile error: Uint8List isn't a type.

```
Uint8List encoded = await CharsetConverter.encode("Big5", name);
  String decoded = await CharsetConverter.decode("UTF-8",
      encoded);
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/big5  try this.

Comment: Yes, I tried this before but just don't know how to convert a big5 string to utf using this package.

Comment: var str = '國立臺灣大學';
    var utf8List = utf8.encode(str);
    pr(utf8List);
    var utf8Str = utf8.decode(utf8List);
    pr(utf8Str);

Answer (score 0):

- The big5 plugin has not been maintained for a long time, so I re-updated this plugin
- [see](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_big5)   <flutter_big5>

Comment: I got compile error: Error: This part doesn't have a containing library.
Try removing the 'part of' declaration.
part of big5;

Comment: oky. it's good now

Comment: sorry, the same. I have uploaded the error msg here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E5I777a3tNcteysONRuzxZjBz-W3PMoa/view?usp=share_link

Comment: you can use ^0.0.6   and  try delete cache file

Comment: sorry bakboem, I know its annoying, but the same happens :(

Comment: omm... let me see

Comment: @TonyLam compile platform?

Comment: There may be some problems with the configuration. In fact, you can also download these two files from the project and reference them [big5.dart](https://github.com/bakboem/big5/blob/master/lib/big5.dart), [table.dart] (https://github.com/bakboem/big5/blob/master/lib/table.dart)

Comment: sorry, I tried on a different machine, same error given

Comment: @TonyLam Have you tried copying the above two files into your project?

Comment: Yes, I am using windows platform

Comment: I got it running, I shouldn't have import the table file.  Now I got "Null check operator used on a null value".  Is this due to the JSon format of the data source?

Comment: String show_utf(name){
  if (name.runes.length == 0) {
    return('');
  }else {
    print(big5.encode(name).toString());
    return ('test');
  }
}

Comment: @TonyLam great! you did it!  about the Null check see [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety).